# Object reference not set to an instance of an object ( but no any reason)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, ado.net

**Exception:**

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Source Error: 


Line 96:                     }
Line 97: 
Line 98:                     dtMajlisOrKabinat.Merge(dtTotalsalaries);
Line 99:                     dtMajlisOrKabinat.AcceptChanges();
Line 100:                    SqlDataAdapter querycountSalDays = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(distinct CONVERT(varchar,Convert(datetime,InsertedOn,103),103)) as SalaryDate from [SALARY EMP] join Hierarchy on [SALARY EMP].BCODE = Hierarchy.BCODE where SMonth = " + monthvar + " and SYear = " + yearvar + " and gender= " + gender + "   AND (UAdmin like '%" + uname + "%' or UserGroup like '%" + uname + "%')", MyGlobalVariables.con);

Source File: F:\Web Payroll\WebPayroll080316\WebPayroll080316 current\WebPayroll080316\DGrid.aspx.cs    Line: 98 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Data.Merger.MergeSchema(DataTable table) +1323
   System.Data.Merger.MergeTableData(DataTable src) +36
   System.Data.Merger.MergeTable(DataTable src) +181
   System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction) +161
   System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table) +13
   WebPayroll080316.DGrid.btnshowgrid_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Web Payroll\WebPayroll080316\WebPayroll080316  current\WebPayroll080316\DGrid.aspx.cs:98
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9696694
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0`
```

exception detail

**.Cs Code**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace mynamespace
{
public partial class GridViewClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static int gender = 1;
    static bool DataLevel = true;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnshowgrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string constr = "Data Source= MyMachineName,1433;Initial Catalog= dbname;Connection Timeout=1 ;User ID= 'username' ;Password= 'password'";
        MyGlobalVariables.con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        MyGlobalVariables.con.Open();



        string uname;


        uname = "myuser";

        int monthvar = ddlmonth.SelectedIndex + 1;
        int yearvar = Convert.ToInt16(ddlyear.SelectedValue);

        SqlCommand queryEmpCount;
        if(DataLevel)
        {
            queryEmpCount = new SqlCommand("StoredProDeptAndEmpCount", MyGlobalVariables.con);

        }
        else
        {
            queryEmpCount = new SqlCommand("StoredProAreaAndEmpCount", MyGlobalVariables.con);
        }

        queryEmpCount.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter Gender = queryEmpCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", gender);

        SqlParameter Uname = queryEmpCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("Uname", uname);

        SqlParameter joindate = queryEmpCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("joindate", "01-05-2016");


        SqlDataReader EmpCountdata = queryEmpCount.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dtDeptorArea = new DataTable();

        dtDeptorArea.Load(EmpCountdata);

        if(dtDeptorArea.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter queryTotalSalary;

            if(DataLevel)
            {
                dtDeptorArea.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtDeptorArea.Columns["DeptCode"] };
                queryTotalSalary = new SqlDataAdapter("select  Hierarchy.DeptCode , mydate.CountEmptotal from Hierarchy full outer join  (select COUNT(EmpCode) as  CountEmptotal,  Hierarchy.DeptCode  from [SALARY EMP] join Hierarchy on Hierarchy.BCODE= [SALARY EMP].BCODE where [SALARY EMP].BCODE in (select BCODE from [SALARY EMP] where (UAdmin like '%" + uname + "%' or UserGroup like '%" + uname + "%') and SMonth = " + monthvar + " and SYear = " + yearvar + " and Hierarchy.gender =" + gender + ") and (UAdmin like '%" + uname + "%' or UserGroup like '%" + uname + "%') and SMonth = " + monthvar + " and SYear = " + yearvar + "   group by Hierarchy.DeptCode)   as mydate  on Hierarchy.DeptCode= mydate.DeptCode where (UAdmin like '%" + uname + "%' or UserGroup like '%" + uname + "%') and gender =" + gender + " group by Hierarchy.Majlisname, Hierarchy.DeptCode, mydate.DeptCode, mydate.CountEmptotal order by Hierarchy.DeptCode", MyGlobalVariables.con);
            }
            else
            {
                dtDeptorArea.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtDeptorArea.Columns["AreaCode"] };

                queryTotalSalary = new SqlDataAdapter("select  Hierarchy.AreaCode , mydate.CountEmptotal from Hierarchy full outer join  (select COUNT(EmpCode) as  CountEmptotal,  Hierarchy.AreaCode  from [SALARY EMP] join Hierarchy on Hierarchy.BCODE= [SALARY EMP].BCODE where [SALARY EMP].BCODE in (select BCODE from [SALARY EMP] where (UAdmin like '%" + uname + "%' or UserGroup like '%" + uname + "%') and SMonth = " + monthvar + " and SYear = " + yearvar + " and Hierarchy.gender =" + gender + ") and (UAdmin like '%" + uname + "%' or UserGroup like '%" + uname + "%') and SMonth = " + monthvar + " and SYear = " + yearvar + "   group by Hierarchy.AreaCode)   as mydate  on Hierarchy.AreaCode= mydate.AreaCode where (UAdmin like '%" + uname + "%' or UserGroup like '%" + uname + "%') and gender =" + gender + " group by Hierarchy.kbname, Hierarchy.AreaCode, mydate.AreaCode, mydate.CountEmptotal order by Hierarchy.AreaCode", MyGlobalVariables.con);
            }
            DataTable dtTotalsalaries = new DataTable();
            queryTotalSalary.Fill(dtTotalsalaries);

            if(DataLevel)
            {

                dtTotalsalaries.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtTotalsalaries.Columns["DeptCode"] };

            }
            else
            {
                dtTotalsalaries.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtTotalsalaries.Columns["AreaCode"] };
            }

            dtDeptorArea.Merge(dtTotalsalaries);
            dtDeptorArea.AcceptChanges();

            grdvsalaryreport.DataSource = dtDeptorArea;
            grdvsalaryreport.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

**Note**
[all both procedure are working and also successfully filled in data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0pxx.png)

**Exception occur on this line :**

```
dtDeptorArea.Merge(dtTotalsalaries);
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace, and reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: Debug your code step by step....

Comment: i debug all code but no find reason it

Comment: The exception isn't on the line where you said it was.

Comment: You can find the implementation [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/Merger@cs/1305376/Merger@cs). Looks like you are merging things that cannot be merged. Look at the content of both tables before merging.

Comment: @Kashif Faraz: You could try to create a third empty DataTable and merge dtDeptorArea and dtTotalsalaries in it.

Comment: You said debugged the code, are you able to debug until end of this method without error?? Is "grdvsalaryreport" instantiated correctly? I would put in more null check and try catch when executing data base queries..

Comment: my queries is ok because i already merge it before some changes and i also attached my query result in note hyperlink image

Comment: @Odrai  I am try merging in new dt

Comment: if i remove condition and execute with storedproDeptandEmpCode only so   compiled sucessfully